# Using Netbeans Platform with JavaFX 2?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2, rcp, netbeans-platform

I am building a desktop application on JavaFX 2, and want to speed up my development --

Is RCP the way to go? How steep is the learning curve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [eFX](http://java.net/projects/efx/pages/Home) project which tries to adapt the NetBeans Platform for JavaFX.

From what I know about the NetBeans Platform source code, I doubt though that they managed to get rid of the Swing dependencies. (This might be important once you want to deploy your application to a platform which doesn't support Swing. See: [Compact Profiles](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/161) and [Project Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/)).

Also it uses the NetBeans Platform module system rather than OSGi (many Apache Commons libraries as well as other libraries come with OSGi meta data but not with NetBeans Platform meta data). There is a way to run OSGi bundle in a NetBeans Platform though, but, of course, this would mean that you have to know 2 module systems.

I also don't know if the NetBeans Platform Maven plugins work with eFX or if you have to use Ant.

As an alternative also note that (mainly for the concerns mentioned above) I've recently released an initial Early Access version of Drombler FX, a modular RCP for JavaFX based on OSGi and Maven (POM-first):

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2012/12/drombler-fx-building-modular-javafx.html

http://wiki.drombler.org/GettingStarted

Comment: I took a look at Drombler FX and looks awesome, sadly it seems like is meant for 100% FX applications where I'll need just a module or two. Is this the case or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, Drombler FX applications are usually 100% JavaFX applications. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have an existing application with normal maven built modules and wanted to add a JavaFX module to add JavaFX graphs and such.

Comment: It's not clear in what way your application is not a 100% JavaFX application. Are you using some other GUI toolkits in the same application as well? Or why do you think does Drombler FX not fit your needs? Maybe I can change something that helps you...

Comment: Well, is a normal Netbeans Application built with Maven. So the application already exists. Just wanted to enhance it with JavaFX modules.